# Getting Spotify user listening history sorted by month?

Tags: javascript, arduino, processing, spotify

Does libspotify allow getting the listening history of a user in the same fashion it is displayed in facebook? eg. May 2012 Top Tracks. How? If not, is there a workaround to pull this data from users facebook account if they give authentication? I would like to use this in a tangible interface using arduino. Thanks a bunch!

p.s. I came across this js code but I'm not sure it provides the top tracks for every month: https://gist.github.com/1792366

Answer (score 1):

Spotify does not currently store/expose any listening history. However, the data that's sent to Facebook can be retrieved using Facebook API.